# Alfresco web-scripts-application-context.xml

Tags: javabeans, alfresco, web-scripting

I want to register a bean. I'am following this tutorial http://aboutalfresco.blogspot.com/2010/07/java-backed-web-scripts.html.

But i can't found the file `tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\web-scripts-application-context.xml`.

1. Is it deprecated ?
2. Should i create it ? or should i use  the file `alfresco\web-client-application-context.xml` wich also define beans ?
3. What is the difference bettwen this 2 files  ? Alfresco version?

I'm using Alfresco 5.0.d.

Comment: You'd better check out this [Alfresco developer series](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series)

Answer (score 3):

In Alfresco 5 many of the context files have been bundled up in jars that you won't be able to access.

Besides, best practice involves you creating your own custom context file rather than overwriting a system context file. Your best bet if you don't want to create an amp is to put your bean definition in a file named something like `custom-webscripts-context.xml` and putting it in `shared/classes/extension`. Alfresco will pick up anything that ends in `-context.xml`.

Also, please don't follow a 5 year old tutorial. The tutorials linked in the comments are created by Jeff Potts, the old Community Manager for Alfresco, so really are the most up to date and easiest to follow you're going to find.